# SQL Table Linked to Access Displays 0 instead of NULL

Tags: sql, ms-access, null, zero

If I link an SQL table with a bit field that has NULL values and open up the linked table in Access, the NULL values are showing up as 0.  I do want the NULL values to show NULL or blank in Access when opening up the table.  I am not sure if this has some recent problem with a Microsoft update but it makes a difference because sometimes we are working on the table directly in Access and want to see if the field value is NULL without doing a search.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I do want the NULL values to show NULL or blank in Access

Maybe. However, this is a known limitation, and it won't happen - except if you change the data type to Integer.

Comment: Thanks.  That coincides with everything I've researched as well.  Too bad about this inconsistency between SQL and Access.

Comment: I  strong suggest you don't allow or use null bits with Access. Always have the bit field default to 0.